# how to know if it's new or edited customer

Tags: magento, events

thanx for reading.
I have an observer Kicks off on adminhtml_customer_save_after event
this event happens after adding a new customer AND after saving in customer edit for a customer that already exists.
how can I know if the event generated because of adding a new customer or saving after editing an existing customer.

thanx in advance

Comment: An new customer doesn't have an id. You can check the id with `if($customer->getId() == "") echo "Customer is most likely new";`. `$customer` is your customer Model.

Comment: NO .. we git new customer id $customer = $observer->getCustomer()->getData(); $id = $customer['entity_id'];

Comment: I think it's some thing like isObjectNew ..

Comment: found this : $object = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();$object->isObjectNew(); .. but it says method is not defined .. any idea

Comment: update: it says calling method isobjectnew on non object

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a doBeforeSave() method listening on adminhtml_customer_save_before and doAfterSave() listening on adminhtml_customer_save_after you can add something to your model on before it's saved and check it after it's saved, fe:

```
public function doBeforeSave($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getId() == 0) {
        $customer->setMyCustomPropertyToCheckIfIsNew(true);
    }
}

public function doAfterSave($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getMyCustomPropertyToCheckIfIsNew()) {
        // This is a new customer being saved!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `$object = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()`